# How to calculate the probability of death between two discrete time periods using survival curves

Tags: survival, hazard, discrete-time

I was hoping somebody could help, I am trying to work out the probability of death between two time points on a survival curve.

i.e. I have my survival curve as follows (this is an example Kaplan-Meier curve).

[image: Survival Curve Example]

What I want to know is between time period 1 and time period 2 represented by the dashed red lines, what is the probability of survival. E.g. if you monitored an animal for this period of time what is the chance that during this discrete period it would die.

I've looked for an answer to this and found "conditional probability of failure", but I'm not too sure this is correct, there are also a number of equations for it which seem to vary. Any simple explanation and pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, a Kaplan-Meier Survival Curve $S(t)$ is an unbiased estimate of $1-F(t)$, where $F(t)$ is the probability that someone alive at time $0$ will be dead by time $t$. What the KM-curve is telling you is that if you started with 100 people at $t=0$ then approximately $S(t_1)$ will be alive at your first red dashed line $t_1$. Since you cannot die twice, we know that the change in survival between $t_1$ and the second red line $t_2$ must be due to deaths of those alive at $t_1$

Hence, of those alive at $t_1$ the probability of death between $t_1$ and $t_2$ (i.e., $P_D([t_1,t_2])$is:

$$P_D([t_1,t_2]|S(t_1),S(t_2)) \approx \frac{S(t_1)-S(t_2)}{S(t_1)}$$

This is just the conditional probability of *not* surviving during this time period.